# Implementing Lodash's debounce in a ReactJS functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash, debouncing

I'm trying to debounce text input field change with Lodash's `debounce` function.

```
import React from "react";
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const Input = () => {

  const onChange = debounce((e) => {
    const { value } = e.target;
    console.log('debounced value', value)
  }, 1000)

  return (

    <input type="text" onChange={ onChange } />

  )
};
```

The code above throws the following errors:

> Warning: This synthetic event is reused for performance reasons. If you're seeing this, you're accessing the property target on a released/nullified synthetic event. This is set to null. If you must keep the original synthetic event around, use event.persist().

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

What is the correct implementation?

Comment: You need to send value in input tag. Refer this post for example implementation: https://medium.com/@rajeshnaroth/using-throttle-and-debounce-in-a-react-function-component-5489fc3461b3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When to Use Refs There are a few good use cases for refs:
>
> - Managing focus, text selection, or media playback.
> - Triggering imperative animations.
> - Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.
>
> Avoid using refs for anything that can be done declaratively.

[Refs and the DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs)

The way you defined `Input`, I am assuming it would be used in many places. So, I would do this:

```
import React from "react";
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const Input = () => {

  // Debounced function
  // `printValue` only cares about last state of target.value
  const printValue = debounce(value => console.log(value), 1000);

  // Event listener called on every change
  const onChange = ({ target }) => printValue(target.value);

  return <input type="text" onChange={ onChange } />;    

};
```

Comment: Thanks. Passing the string `event.target.value` instead of the entire `event` to `debounce` was indeed the way. `react@^16.12.0` `"@chakra-ui/react": "^1.0.0"`

Answer (score 1):

If we don't need to rely on any internal component state/props in our `onChange` handler, we should be able to lift the debounced function call out of the component (to avoid it being recreated on each render), which means we don't need to use refs or `useCallback`:

```
import debounce from "lodash.debounce";

import Input from "./Input";

const handleChange = debounce(({ target }) => {
  console.log(target.value);
}, 500);

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <label htmlFor="input-first-name">First name</label>
      <Input id="input-first-name" name="firstName" onChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-input-debounce-feleu9?file=/src/App.js&expanddevtools=1

Answer (score 0):

The fix was not to retrieve the value from the event but from the input directly with a ref.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import debounce from 'lodash.debounce';

const Input = () => {

  const input = useRef( null )

  const onChange = debounce(() => {
    console.log('debounced value', input.current.value)
  }, 1000)

  return (

    <input ref={ input } type="text" onChange={ onChange } />

  )
};
```

Comment: You do not need to use a ref in this.

Comment: So how do I retrieve the value without using the state? If there's a better approach, I'd appreciate some more explanation.

Comment: `onChange` passes the entire event as a variable; you can then access the current value using `event.target.value`.

Comment: This is bad practice. No one should do this without a very good reason.